# Spring Boot-Activiti Integration with Sybase Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sybase, activiti

I created a spring-boot project to read and write data to Sybase database. The project was working as intended. However, whenever I added activiti dependencies, It says "couldn't deduct database type from database product name 'Adaptive Server Enterprise'". According to my understanding, there are some classes conflicting each other in activiti and spring even though I do not use anything regarding activiti( except the fact that I just opened a folder called processes in the resources directory).

The activiti dependencies I added are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>5.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>5.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

To clarify my point in this, I wanted to use activiti just for workflow purposes and leave the rest of the ETL or database job to spring. If I change database from Sybase to Mysql, the project also works fine even with activiti dependencies. As far as I know activiti has no support for Sybase and apparently, it tries to interfere everything possible and overrides something that was already working at the first place. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use the spring boot starter which automatically tries to configure a database using spring autoconfiguration. Can you clarify with which database do you want to use Activiti? If you want to use Sybase you will need to contribute back to the project with Sybase support. Alternatively, you can not use the starter and depend on the engine directly, this will push you to provide the engine configurations for your spring environment. You can also check the -starter project and adapt as needed.

HTH